# Error when running docker -H ssh://user@hostname by Go Exec lib

Tags: docker, go, ssh, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a container on a raspberrypi remotelly usign GO. The following code is a simplified snippet of the original.

```golang
    command := "docker -H ssh://pi@raspberrypi.local compose -f /tmp/code/docker-compose.yml up -d"

    parsedCommand := parseCommand(command)

    fmt.Println(command)

    cmd := exec.Command(parsedCommand[0], parsedCommand[1:]...)

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

I already have a ssh key for making this connection and if i run the commando manually it works well, but running by Go i got this error:

```
docker -H ssh://pi@raspberrypi.local compose -f /tmp/code/docker-compose.yml up -d
error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Djanus%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": ssh resolves to executable in current directory (./ssh)
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the answer by my self after a few tests.

The error essage is not very clear about it, but we need to pass the OS env vars to the exec.Cmd that was created with `cmd.Env = os.Environ()`

here is the full code example:

```golang
    command := "docker -H ssh://pi@raspberrypi.local compose -f /tmp/code/docker-compose.yml up -d"

    parsedCommand := parseCommand(command)

    fmt.Println(command)

    cmd := exec.Command(parsedCommand[0], parsedCommand[1:]...)

    cmd.Env = os.Environ()

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```